# com.couchbase.client.java.error.ViewDoesNotExistException: View blogs/all does not exist."

Tags: spring-boot, couchbase

`OnError` while emitting `onNext` value:

```java
com.couchbase.client.java.document.json.JsonObject.class
        at rx.exceptions.OnErrorThrowable.addValueAsLastCause(OnErrorThrowable.java:118) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeMap.java:73) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeMap.java:77) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.producers.SingleProducer.request(SingleProducer.java:65) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
        at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:211) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.setProducer(OnSubscribeMap.java:102) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.setProducer(OnSubscribeMap.java:102) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSingle$ParentSubscriber.onCompleted(OperatorSingle.java:113) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.checkTerminated(OperatorObserveOn.java:281) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.call(OperatorObserveOn.java:216) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_151]
```

Comment: Hi, Tejaswini. Try to add some code which produces this error

Comment: Can you add some of your code please? It'd be much easier for us to help you thaat way. Please edit your question to do so. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using reactive Spring Data, and potentially using some method like removeAll/listAll. Before SDK 3 those methods still use views internally, so in order to use then you have to add the annotation @ViewIndexed:

```
@ViewIndexed(designDoc = "blogs")
```